# C++ Steady Clock Returning 0 time elapsed, sometimes?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use steady clock to benchmark parts of my code and I'm pulling some hair out here. It seems that sometimes it returns the difference between 2 times, and sometimes it just returns 0.

I have the following code. This is not real code in my prog but illustrates the problem

```
typedef std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point clock_point;

for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {

    clock_point start_overall = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for ( int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++ ) {
        int q = 4;
    }

    clock_point end_phase_1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "DIFF=" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( end_phase_1 - start_overall ).count() << "\n";

}
```

This gives me the following output from running the prog 4 times:

```
DIFF=15622
DIFF=0

DIFF=12968
DIFF=13001

DIFF=12966
DIFF=13997

DIFF=0
DIFF=0
```

Very frustrating!! i need some consistent times here. And Its not like the time needed to loop 10,000,000 times is completely irrelevant. In my actual program, there's much more going on in the loop and it takes significantly longer, but i still sometimes get 0 vals for time differences.

Whats going on? How can I fix this so i get reliable time differences? Thanks

EDIT: Ok because the explanation I'm getting is that the compiler is simplifying out the loop because nothing actually happens in it, I'm going to show you the actual code in the actual loop that runs, between the 2 clock points

```
    // need to reset some variables with each situation
    // these are global vars so can access throughout (ewww)
    this_sit_phase_1_complete = dataVars.phase_1_complete;
    this_sit_on_the_play = dataVars.on_the_play;
    this_sit_start_drawing_cards = dataVars.start_drawing_cards;
    this_sit_current_turn = dataVars.current_turn;
    this_sit_max_turn = dataVars.max_turn;


    // note: do i want a separate split count for each scenario?
    // mmm yeah.. THIS IS WHAT I SHOULD DO INSTEAD OF GLOBAL VARS....
    dataVars.scen_active_index = i;
        
                    
    // point to the split count we want to use
    // dataVars.use_scen_split_count = &dataVars.scen_phase_1and2_split_counts[i];
    dataVars.split_count[i] += 1;
    
    
    // PHASE 1:
    // if we're on the play, we execute first turn without drawing a card
    // just a single split to start in a single que
    // phase 1 won't be complete until we draw a card tho
    // create the all_splits_phase_1 for each situation        
    all_splits_que all_splits_phase_1;
    
    
    // SPLIT STRUCT
    // create the first split in the scenario
    split_struct first_split_struct;            
    // set vars to track splits
    first_split_struct.split_id = dataVars.split_count[i];
    // first_split_struct.split_trail = std::to_string(dataVars.split_count[i]);
    // set remaining vars
    first_split_struct.cards_in_hand_numbs = dataVars.scen_hand_card_numbs[i];
    first_split_struct.cards_in_deck_numbs = dataVars.scen_initial_decks[i];
    first_split_struct.cards_bf_numbs = dataVars.scen_bf_card_numbs[i];
    first_split_struct.played_a_land = false;
    


    // store the split struct as the initial split    
    all_splits_phase_1 = { first_split_struct };


    // if we're on the play, execute first turn without 
    // drawing any cards
    if ( this_sit_on_the_play ) {
       
        // execute the turn on the play before drawing anything
        execute_turn(all_splits_phase_1);

        // move to next turn
        this_sit_current_turn += 1;
    }


    // ok so now, regardless of if we were on the play or not, we have to draw
    // a card for every remaining card in each split, and then execute a turn
    // once these splits are done, we can convert over to phase 2
    do_draw_every_card( all_splits_phase_1 );


    // execute another turn after drawing one of everything,
    // we wont actually draw anything within the turn
    execute_turn( all_splits_phase_1 );


    // next turn
    this_sit_current_turn += 1;


    clock_point end_phase_1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    benchmarker[dataVars.scen_active_index].phase_1_t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( end_phase_1 - start_overall ).count();
```

There is LOTS happening here, lots and lots, the compiler would never simplify out this block. And yet I'm getting 0's as i explained.

Comment: `for ( int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++ ) { int q = 4; }`. I see a chance that the compiler recognized that your loop doesn't have any side-effect. Hence, it generates no code for it. So, what you measure are two consecutive calls of `std::chrono::steady_clock::now();`. Hence, it might happen that the clock wasn't updated between the two calls - looking like if no time has passed. (To prove me right or wrong, you may have a look into generated code e.g. on CompilerExplorer.)

Comment: The loop is most likely optimized out, and the ≈14 msec are a context switch to another process.

Comment: To add, if using something of known duration and that does not get optimized out, the results are consistent, so the two calls two steady_clock should work, unless something is wrong with your setup or your code is optimized out too) https://ideone.com/mm5pik

Comment: With the given snippet of your EDIT:, it's hard to justify what the compiler will do. The essential problem with this: it's not complete. So, it's not possible to track by eyes (at least, for me) what might be eliminated by the compiler due to being compile time computable or lacking side effects. Though, the compiler itself is much better in this analysis and the things described in my answer apply for complex code as well. ;-)

Comment: Your `steady_clock` has a precision of `nanoseconds`.  What happens when you don't truncate to `microseconds`?

Answer (score 1):

Out of OPs code:

```
    for ( int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++ ) {
        int q = 4;
    }
```

This is a repeated assignment to a local variable which isn't used anywhere.

I strongly assume that the compiler is clever enough to recognize that there is no side-effect caused by the loop. Hence it doesn't emit any code for the loop – for proper (and legal) optimization.

To check this, I completed OPs code snippet to the following MCVE:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point clock_point;

int main()
{
for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {

    clock_point start_overall = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for ( int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++ ) {
        int q = 4;
    }

    clock_point end_phase_1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "DIFF=" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( end_phase_1 - start_overall ).count() << "\n";

}
}
```

and compiled with `-O2 -Wall -std=c++17` on CompilerExplorer:

[image: snapshot of godbolt.org]

[**Live Demo on CompilerExplorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/dqTbjs)

Please, note that the lines for the loop are not colored.

The reason is (as I assumed): **there is no code emitted for the `for`-loop.**

So, OP measures two consecutive calls of `std::chrono::steady_clock::now();` which may (or may not) appear in a sub-clock-tick time. Thus, it looks if no time has been passed between these calls.

---

To prevent such optimizations, the code has to contain something which causes side-effects that the compiler cannot foresee during compile time. Input/output operations are an option. So, the loop could contain an assignment from a variable determined by input and assign results to a container determined for output.

Marking variables as `volatile` could be an option as well because it forces the compiler to assign the variable in any case even if it cannot "see" side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code. In `debug` I see the correct difference. In `release` it's `0`-es. Optimized assignment is my assumption. Try in `debug`, or flag `int q` to `volatile int q`

Comment: i simplified a problem and now the explanation is that the problem is too simple. Just pretend there's important code in the block?